# XSL - Transform Date

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working with an XML file that has dates in the YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS format, for example:

```
<NoteDate>2013-05-14T00:00:00</NoteDate>
```

I would like to transform this into AUS date format - DD/MM/YYYY - as part of my XSL which current does a raw import like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Transactions">

<ROW MODID="" RECORDID="">
<COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="Id"/></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="NoteDate"/></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="Reference"/></DATA></COL>
</ROW>

</xsl:for-each>
```

Is there a way I can change the NoteDate in the XSL into the required format?

Comment: What XSLT-version do you use?

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

Comment: It's not the version number in the stylesheet that matters, it's the version of XSLT supported by the processor you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this XSLT-1.0 snippet:

```
<xsl:template match="/Transactions">
    <xsl:for-each select="NoteDate">
      <xsl:variable name="year"  select="substring-before(.,'-')" />
      <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'-'),'-')" />
      <xsl:variable name="day"   select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(.,'-'),'-'),'T')" />
      <Date><xsl:value-of select="concat($day,'/',$month,'/',$year)"/></Date>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output:**

```
<Date>14/05/2013</Date>
```

Feel free to adapt that to your own XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `XSLT 1.0`, another way to achieve this, is to use the **XSLT Extensions** ([EXSLT](http://exslt.org/)).

In order to use extensions, you need to include the appropriate namespace in the XSLT. In this case, since we are formatting the date, we would use the below namespace

```
xmlns:dt="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
```

Using function *format-date*, the desired format can be achieved.

```
<formattedDate>
    <xsl:value-of select="dt:format-date(NoteDate,'dd/MM/yyyy')" />
</formattedDate>
```

Output

```
<formattedDate>14/05/2013</formattedDate>
```